# How to access SVG animateMotion events in Angular?

Tags: angular, svg, svg-animate

The`animateMotion` element fires three events: `onbegin`,`onrepeat` and `onend`. In pure Javascript I can bind an eventlistener like this:

```
<circle r="15" fill="red">
    <animateMotion
        dur="10s" 
        begin="indefinite" 
        repeatCount="indefinite" 
        calcMode="linear"
        repeatCount="indefinite" 
        path="...."
    />
</circle>


var anim = document.getElementsByTagName("animateMotion");

anim.onrepeat = function() {
    alert("repeat")
}
anim.onbegin = function() {
    alert("start")
}
anim.onend = function() {
    alert("end")
}
```

But how can I get access to these event in Angular 9? Is there any way to get access to the events?

Thx in advance,
Lars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the updated approach below as my initial assumption was indeed inaccurate, since I was not too familiar with those specific events.

Update: my initial assumption was that the below would work - **was proved wrong**:

```
<svg:circle r="15" fill="red">
    <svg:animateMotion (repeat)="repeatMethodInsideTs()"
        dur="10s" 
        begin="indefinite" 
        repeatCount="indefinite" 
        calcMode="linear"
        repeatCount="indefinite" 
        path="...."
    />
</svg:circle>
```

Note in your template the XML of svg should have "svg" for each tag.

Then I decided to still see if there are equivalent events we can just bind to in angular in a clean fashion and viola:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <svg:path fill="none" stroke="lightgrey"
    d="M20,50 C20,-50 180,150 180,50 C180-50 20,150 20,50 z" />

  <svg:circle r="5" fill="red">
    <svg:animateMotion (beginEvent)="begin($event)" (repeatEvent)="repeat($event)" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"
      path="M20,50 C20,-50 180,150 180,50 C180-50 20,150 20,50 z" />
  </svg:circle>
</svg>
```

Now in ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  repeat(event) {
    console.log("repeat event called", event)
  }

  begin(event) {
    console.log("repeat event called", event)
  }
}
```

Here is stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-px8uf3

Comment: this is not the solution. Angular doesn't handle these events. But I've found a solution in `ngAfterViewInit() { this.innerTrack = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('#innerTrack'); this.innerTrack.onbegin  = () => { ... } }` That works fine.

Comment: So I updated the answer with solution. You are right straight away using (repeat) does not work in Angular, but using (repeatEvent) does. Please check. Your solution works as well but does introduce DOM level API, which is less optimal.

Comment: awesome. Thx. you so much. Maybe, do you also have a solution for this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61136896/how-to-do-stop-pause-resume-svg-animations-with-angular-9

Comment: Ok will check!:)